# WSO2 API Manager API Visiblity

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In API Manager, for a given API, I have set API visibility to RoleA only. RoleB is not allowed to see API in store. But users of RoleB can see the API. What am I missing?

Comment: Any comment why -1?

Comment: What is the APIM version?

Comment: What are the permissions in RoleB?

Comment: Login. Publisher, Subscriber, Create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin user is able to see the APIs, visibility restricted by roles. Admin user is a special user with all the privileges. Can you create a new user with Internal/Subscriber role and check the same. Then it should work.

Comment: This happens not only for admin user. What can be the reason?

Comment: What are the roles assigned to the user you tested?

Comment: New roles. RoleA and RoleB

Comment: According to the comments above you have set Visibility to RoleA "I have set API visibility to RoleA"

Comment: What are the Permissions the RoleB has? Seems you have given all permissions to this role

Comment: Login. Publisher, Subscriber, Create.

Comment: If the user has publisher permissions the API is visible to the user. Can you try removing Publisher permissions from the RoleB